# How to represent a method call in a loop in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I know that one use a box with "loop" in the corner, when we have a loop which uses several objects. Is it the same with just one object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can place a `loop` fragment over a self-call and that simply means a repetitive call. A guard placed in square brackets (top left of the fragment) tells when the loop will end.

However, graphical programming isn't the best idea at all. For such trivial cases some note or pseudo code are better suited. In most cases that info is obvious from the context anyway and should not be presented graphically. Don't underestimate the programmers doing the coding in the end.